# Django, understanding HttpRequest

Tags: django, httprequest

I am newer to Django and wanted clarification on an issue I noticed with HttpRequest. It appears that when you request a page the default request.method is GET. My question is, are all page request GETs be default, unless you specify POST or otherwise?

I had thought that GET was related to submission forms and had to be defined in HTML, but Django views in my project that have no forms or anything show request.method == GET.

I searched google and Django but that did not clarify things for me, if you understand this better please share.

Thanks.

Comment: You actually have them backwards.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a Django-specific question, it's much more general.

- `GET` is the default request method for browser-based HTTP requests, intended for reading resources from the server.
- Other methods, such as `POST`, `PUT`, and `DELETE`, generally require a form submission (for user-initiated requests in a browser) or explicit headers (for script-initiated requests). These methods are intended for user actions that create, update, or delete data on the server.

See the [W3 HTTP 1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) for more information on the different types of request methods.